# Deny requests for other domains in Apache 2

Tags: domain, virtualhost, apache-2.4, hosts-file

Let's say I have xy.com running on a server powered by Apache. It's the default virtual host.
Now someone has rewritten his hosts file to redirect yz.com to my server's IP. As my server doesn't know a thing about yz.com, it just resolves it to the default virtual host. So in this case yz.com/hello get's resolved to xy.com/hello and it tries to serve my site's /hello page.
Is there a way (maybe with a RewriteRule or something) to disable requests requesting yz.com from my server? Give them a 403 for example or anything, just don't let anything through Apache unless it's requesting xy.com.

I'm using the latest Apache version on Ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 5):

Why is xy.com the default if you don't want it to be?

Add a new default virtual host that does nothing but return a 404.

Then add xy.com as a virtual host entry. It'll only get used if requested.

Answer (score 5):

Why not simply change the default VHost to a deny one?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lol.no
    DocumentRoot /var/empty/httpd
    <Location />
        Deny from all
        Allow from none
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...your VHost goes here...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

A RewriteRule would be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^your\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Other solution would be to add a new default Virtual Host which responds with 403 to any requests.
Only matching requests would then go to your real Virtual Host.